# How to capture which treeview node is clicked

Tags: c, winapi, treeview

I created a tree view controls using WinApi. I want to capture mouse click on checkboxes. The notification message NM_CLICK contains NMHDR, which has no information about the node being clicked. since the clicked node may be different from the selected node, there should be a way to find which node has been checked or unchecked, It could be HTREEITEM, or lParam Inserted when adding items to tree view. I want to capture the checking/unchecking in real time. How can I specify which Node being checked/unchecked? any help or link appreciated.
mr.abzadeh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a [TVM_HITTEST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773732.aspx) message (or use the [TreeView_HitTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773897.aspx) macro) to find the tree view item, given a client-relative coordinate.

To get the cursor position at the time the `NM_CLICK` message was generated, use the [GetMessagePos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644938.aspx) API.

This allows you do monitor any mouse click in the client area of the control. If you are interested in the state changes as the result of the standard tree view control implementation, you can handle the [TVN_ITEMCHANGING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773530.aspx) or [TVN_ITEMCHANGED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773526.aspx) notifications instead. Both supply an [NMTVITEMCHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773425.aspx) structure, where the `hItem` identifies the item being changed, and `lParam` carries application specific data.

Comment: downvote as bad and not effective solution for OP question - "How can I specify which Node being checked/unchecked?"

Comment: you add info about   `TVN_ITEMCHANGING` and `TVN_ITEMCHANGED` notifications **already after** I wrote own answer with this - which is visible by edit history. this is how minimum not nice :)

Comment: @RbMm: Since you haven't quite grasped, how this place works, please take the [tour] and visit the [help]. Incorporating suggestions from feedback **is** the right thing to do.

Comment: again - you initially give the bad solution, based on wrong OP assumption that need capture mouse click direct. than you copy paste info from my answer. and event not noted this in edit comments. so in what your problem ?

Comment: @RbMm: Why do you insist, that you do not need to take the [tour]? It might just tell you a thing or two you didn't know.

Comment: It is important to mention that TVN_ITEMCHANGING is available from Vista onwards, otherwise OP must use hittesting.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: That's correct. Still, though, being supported from Windows Vista onward means, that it is available for all supported versions of Windows.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to capture the checking/unchecking in real time. How can I
>   specify which Node being checked/unchecked?

for this exist notification [TVN_ITEMCHANGING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773530(v=vs.85).aspx) and [TVN_ITEMCHANGED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773526(v=vs.85).aspx) - look for `uStateNew` and `uStateOld` members of [`NMTVITEMCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773425(v=vs.85).aspx) - when tree view have checkboxes (`TVS_CHECKBOXES` style) it used as state image list with 2 images - `unchecked` and `checked`.

so `state & TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK` will be `0` when no checkbox, `INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(1)` for unchecked and `INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(2)` for checked. based on this info we can and capture mouse click on checkboxes

by using [TVN_ITEMCHANGING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773530(v=vs.85).aspx) you can also prevent the change when you return TRUE for this notification. if you need only notify - use [TVN_ITEMCHANGED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773526(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
    case WM_NOTIFY:
        {
            union {
                LPARAM lp;
                NMTVITEMCHANGE  *pnm;
                NMHDR* phdr;
            };
            lp = lParam;

            switch (phdr->code)
            {
            case TVN_ITEMCHANGING:
                {
                    UINT CheckStateOld = pnm->uStateOld & TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
                    UINT CheckStateNew = pnm->uStateNew & TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;

                    if (CheckStateNew != CheckStateOld)
                    {
                        PCSTR szstate = "??";
                        switch (CheckStateNew)
                        {
                        case INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(1):
                            szstate = "uncheck";
                            break;
                        case INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(2):
                            szstate = "check";
                            break;
                        }
                        DbgPrint("%p>%s\n", pnm->lParam, szstate);
                    }
                }
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
```

---

also read [How to Work With State Image Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh270424(v=vs.85).aspx)

> ```
>   // Image 1 in the tree-view check box image list is the unchecked box. 
>   // Image 2 is the checked box.
>
>   tvItem.state = INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK((fCheck ? 2 : 1));
> ```

---

notification [TVN_ITEMCHANGING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773530(v=vs.85).aspx) and [TVN_ITEMCHANGED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773526(v=vs.85).aspx) is available begin from Windows Vista. if you need XP support too - on xp only option use @IInspectable [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434832/how-to-capture-which-treeview-node-is-clicked/41434977#41434977)

Comment: It is important to mention that TVN_ITEMCHANGING is available from Vista onwards, otherwise OP must use hittesting.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff yes.., i miss this. my mistake

Comment: Not a mistake, just something important to mention. I have upvoted your answer.